# Как прочитать фото файл для загрузки в Bitmap?

Tags: java, android, bitmap

Пытаюсь загрузить изображение в Bitmap таким способом

```
 File fileRead = new File(Environment.
                        getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS),"My_Folder"+"/"+"0001.png");
 Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(fileRead.getAbsolutePath());
```

на выходе получаю
bmp = null
Как правильно загружить картинку с папки  в  Bitmap -для ее последующей обработки ?

Comment: Посмотрите на логи, возможно проблема с пермишенами